# Delete item from database when quantity set to 0 is not working. Only deleted from array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

At the comment section, supposed i want to delete it from database but it's not working. i want it when user set the quantity to 0 then item in database is deleted. it only deleted in array.

```
<?php
        /*require_once('Connections/catalogue.php');*/
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['quantity']))
            foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val)
            {
                if($val==0)
                {
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                    /* $sql_delete="DELETE FROM `maklumat_belian` WHERE id_produk=id";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql_delete);
                    if ($result)
                    header("Location: products.php?page=cart"); */

                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val; 
                } 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: you'll need to pass the product id to be used in the DELETE statement, and yes its not working since the mysql code is incomplete and commented

Comment: @Ghost im just giving the code section only and im commented it to highlight the statement so that you guys know which section im talking about. btw, thank you for your tips. appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If product id is $_SESSION['cart'][$key]

```
$id_produk = $_SESSION['cart'][$key];
```

If product id is $key

```
$id_produk = $key;
```

code:

```
<?php
    /*require_once('Connections/catalogue.php');*/
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['quantity']))
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val)
        {
            if($val==0)
            {
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);

                $id_produk = $_SESSION['cart'][$key]; # Asssign the product id

                $sql_delete="DELETE FROM `maklumat_belian` WHERE id_produk='$id_produk'";
                $result=mysql_query($sql_delete);
                /*if ($result)
                header("Location: products.php?page=cart");*/

            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val; 
            } 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: both code from you and @lov2code seems fine, but i have error saying that `Notice: Undefined offset: 128`. the number 128 i assume is a product number.

Comment: that error already fixed and this code is working. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$_SESSION['cart'][$key]` is the product id in the database, you first need to remove the comment tags from your PHP code (`/**/`). So this should work if you replace it with your current sql query:

```
if($val==0){
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);

  $sql_delete="DELETE FROM `maklumat_belian` WHERE id_produk=".$_SESSION['cart'][$key];
  $result=mysql_query($sql_delete);

  if ($result){
    header("Location: products.php?page=cart");
  }
}
```

Just a side not, I highly recommend using something like PDO for security purposes. Using mysql_query and direct id insertion will put you at risk for attacks. Just food for thought. Hope this helps!